# extract values and construct new file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have "vtu" format file (for paraview) as a text. The format is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian" >
<UnstructuredGrid>
<Piece NumberOfPoints="21" NumberOfCells="20" >
<Points>
<DataArray type="Float64" Name="coordinates" NumberOfComponents="3" format="ascii" >
                  -3.3333333333e-01 1.1111111111e-01 0.0000000000e+00
 -2.7777777778e-01 1.1111111111e-01 0.0000000000e+00
 -1.1111111111e-01 4.4444444445e-01 0.0000000000e+00
</DataArray>
</Points>
<Cells>
<DataArray type="UInt64" Name="connectivity" NumberOfComponents="1" format="ascii" >
       0 1
 2 3
 5 4
```

It is representing a mesh file. 
I would like to extract the value for NumberOfPoints and also the first two coordinate and store them in another file as following:

```
21
-3.3333333333e-01
1.1111111111e-01
-2.7777777778e-01
1.1111111111e-01
-1.1111111111e-01
4.4444444445e-01
```

I am not familiat with python, I could only read the file line by line but I don't know to construct the above file.

What I have learnt so far is very simple. For the first file I am able to detect the line NumberOfPoints is included by

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('read.vtu')
root = tree.getroot()

for Piece in root.iter('Piece'):
  print Piece.attrib
  nr = Piece.get('NumberOfPoints')
  print nr
```

I can I have 21 :) the next step is to add Coordinate. But I dont know how to parse them, since I cannot find any node connected to them.

Comment: As a very first step: Since this is a XML file, I suggest using xml library to parse it: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive

Comment: You should use beautiful soup to avoid headache while parsing xml (if the file is short )

Comment: I solved some part, but I cannot get the coordinates still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except:
    from StringIO import StringIO

o = file('out.txt', 'w')

tree = ET.parse('read.vtu')
root = tree.getroot()

for Piece in root.iter('Piece'):
  nr = Piece.get('NumberOfPoints')
  o.write(nr+ '\n')

piece = root.iter('Piece') 
piece = piece.next()
point = piece.getchildren()[0]
dataArr = point.getchildren()
data = dataArr[0]

# Writing to a buffer
output = StringIO()
output.write(data.text)

# Retrieve the value written
crds = output.seek(1)

for l in output:
  ls = l.split( );
  o.write(ls[0]+ '\n')
  o.write(ls[1]+ '\n')

output.close()
o.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

[meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) (a project of mine) knows the VTU format, so you could simply

```
pip install meshio
```

and then

```
import meshio
points, cells, _, _, _ = meshio.read('file.vtu')
```